# I want to make a function in python that runs every 5 seconds until a variable reaches 100%

Tags: python

So I would like to create a function that prints out the progress of the rebuild and the time left to finish this rebuild. But it needs to end once the rebuild reaches 100%. This is what I have so far:

```
def progress():
    # This prints out the time left until rebuild is done.
    loudEchoCMD("storage::rebuild-eta")
    # This prints out the % of the rebuild that is done.
    rebuildProgress = loudEchoCMD("storage::rebuild-progress") 
    print rebuildProgress 
    if rebuildProgress != '100%':
        global t 
        t = threading.Timer(5.0, progress)
        t.start()
    else:
        t.cancel()
```

When I start the rebuild process it will first finish that and then start the threading instead of having the threading print out the progress and the ETA every five seconds.

Comment: Whoops sorry fixed now. Thank you deadly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When I start the rebuild process it will first finish that and then
>   start the threading

Start the rebuild process in a different thread.

```
import threading
build = threading.Thread(target = start_rebuild)
build.start()
progress()
build.join()  # wait for build thread to end
```

Also, assuming `progress` takes less than 5 seconds to complete, I think it suffices to omit `global t` and `t.cancel`:

```
def progress():
    # This prints out the time left until rebuild is done.
    loudEchoCMD("storage::rebuild-eta")
    # This prints out the % of the rebuild that is done.
    rebuildProgress = loudEchoCMD("storage::rebuild-progress") 
    print rebuildProgress 
    if rebuildProgress != '100%':
        t = threading.Timer(5.0, progress)
        t.start()
```

Comment: But wouldn't this do the same thing. The start_rebuild starts, ends, progress() starts?

Comment: The rebuild will occur in a separate thread, leaving the main thread available to call progress.

Comment: So this will first start whatever is in the start_rebuild function and while the start_rebuild function is happening it will every five seconds print out the progress? Because that would be perfect :D

Comment: Yes, I believe that's what it will do. Best to try it out and see :)